# how do we know how many pages a pdf file is within the Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

is there anyway we could say know how many pages a pdf file is within the Chrome browser? like say because i often like to open my pdf files in chrome and its realy annoying that i can't know how many pages that pdf file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the keyboard shortcut to print. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

The dialog box will show you how many pages can be printed.

Then cancel. <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Note: Shortcuts are for Windows.

Comment: nice hack